# How to get the difference between two dates in F#?

Tags: f#

Below is my attempt in creating a function that calculates the difference between two dates.

```
let test date =
    let today = DateTime.Now
    let fromdate = DateTime.Parse(date)
    let count = Convert.ToInt32(today - fromdate)
    date
```

The above code prompts the error

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Comment: What unit are you even trying to return?

Comment: you should also return `count` and not `date` from your function. assuming you're looking for the count.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between two DateTimes will give you a [TimeSpan object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), on which you can further operate. This should be the last statement in your function, as it will be used as the return value. You can check the MS docs in the link for the various properties and methods. Strictly speaking, this is part of the BCL, so it's rather .NET than just F# (you would do the same in VB or C#). If you want to further refine your function you should examine [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) as well and handle the possibility of not receiving a valid date.

```
open System

let test date =
    let today = DateTime.Now
    let fromdate = DateTime.Parse(date)
    (today - fromdate).Days

test "2017/12/31" // val it : int = -325
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert the time span resulting from applying the "minus" operator to two dates.
The screenshot below is my attempt at fixing your function and an example of value it returns.

[image: Result of applying the fixed function]